# Node.js MySQL module, auto reconnect db on connection close

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-mysql

I have been using this Node.js MySQL module for handling DB. My connection is placed in a separate file as a module. Here is the code

```
let mysql = function connect(){
    return require('mysql').createConnection({
        hostname: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'chat_db'
    });
}
module.exports.connect = mysql;
```

I want to modify it a bit, so that, incase any disconnection happens, it automatically reconnects itself

Answer (score 2):

You can write reconnection code yourself, but that will probably take a while to get right and I don't think it will be easy. I would recommend using a connection pool to keep several connections to mysql open and use them when needed. This would allow you to periodically check if a connection is still alive and destroy/reconnect if it isn't. Managing a pool can be a lot easier than managing one very important connection.

It looks like there is connection pooling in the library you're using:

> Rather than creating and managing connections one-by-one, this module also provides built-in connection pooling using mysql.createPool(config)

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections

Another option for pooling that I have had success with is [generic-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool). A setup with generic-pool might look like this:

```
const pool = require('generic-pool');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connections = pool.createPool({
  create: (done) => {
    return mysql.createConnection({
      hostname: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'chat_db'
    }).connect(done);
  },
  destroy: connection => connection.destroy(),
  validate: connection => connection.threadId,
}, {
  testOnBorrow: true,
  acquireTimeoutMillis: 10000,
  min: 1,
  max: size,
});
```

Comment: I used the same configuration for generic pool. I created a connection and did some query. After than I killed the process from mysql using "show processlist;", to simulate the lost connection. But when I did query after that, it gave me an error as "Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection."